# macOS Sierra, system size is 180+ GB!

Tags: macos, storage

I have a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) running macOS Sierra, the Mac started to be slow due to storage.

When I've checked my storage I was shocked, from 250 GB I have, 180 GB was allocated to the System it self!

I've checked my friends storage and found that the System is only 30 GB!

How can I manage this and why do I have that much storage allocated to the System?

[image]

Comment: @klanomath The newer one has far more views and the accepted answer has named the software correctly, I often vote to close the other way round and made a judgement call in this case as I would do normally. Do you feel strongly it should have been the other way round?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download [Diskkeeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/download/latest/OmniDiskSweeper) and analyze your hard drive.

> OmniDiskSweeper will show you the files on your drive, in descending
>   order by size, and letting you decide what to do with them. Delete
>   away, but exercise caution.

Omnidiskkeeper will show detail of space usage:

Select System and start cleaning.
[image]

Comment: Im using clean my mac, its the same, and can't do anything with system files

Comment: omnidiskkeeper can show how big the system directory is,just click in and delete,or can you take a snapshot of your system usage?